# Conditionally removing rows changing all values to NA

Tags: r

I have a data frame which has multiple columns.. The first column doesn't have a name, so R is giving Col1 header to it.I have to remove certain rows from the data frame which have Value "tbd" in Col1.

Data frame:

```
Col1   Name   Addreess
<NA>   ABC    ddfddf
<NA>   XYZ    HJJJ
<NA>   KKL    PPOI
tbd    HGGF   UYTT
<NA>   fFFF   OOOO
```

I used the below code to do it,

```
df1<- df[!(df$Col1=="tbd"), ]
```

and writing the output in excel format. But, the output is not removing the tbd rows and changing all the values in the dataframe to NA

Comment: Try `subset(df1, is.na(Col1))` or `subset(df1, !Col1 %in% 'tbd')`.  If there are only NA elements and 'tbd', then use the `is.na` to get those rows having NA or if we need to specifically target 'tbd', then `%in%` or `!=` i.e. `subset(df1, Col1 != 'tbd')`

Comment: I tried using both.. I am getting the error-Error in FUN(left) : invalid argument to unary operator

Comment: Please check the `str(df1)`.  It will give you ideas.  Normally, this should work as I was able to get the output based on the example showed

Comment: Check the solution withe data I used `df1 <- structure(list(Col1 = c(NA, NA, NA, "tbd", NA), Name = c("ABC", 
"XYZ", "KKL", "HGGF", "fFFF"), Addreess = c("ddfddf", "HJJJ", 
"PPOI", "UYTT", "OOOO")), .Names = c("Col1", "Name", "Addreess"
), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")`  The third solution may not work as I didn't test earlier, but other two should work

Comment: For yours it's working.. When I tried using str(df1) for the original file. it listed me  $ Col1               : chr  NA NA NA tbd... which is again in the similar format but giving me error when i am trying to use that function.. I am importing this dataframe from an excel sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution using a loop. It's not the most elegant way to solve that, but helps.

First your data frame

```
Col1 <- c(NA,NA,NA,'tbd',NA)
Name <- c('ABC','XYZ','KKL','HGGF','fFFF')
Addreess <- c('ddfddf','HJJJ','PPOI','UYTT','OOOO')
df <- data.frame(Col1,Name,Addreess)
> df
  Col1 Name Addreess
1 <NA>  ABC   ddfddf
2 <NA>  XYZ     HJJJ
3 <NA>  KKL     PPOI
4  tbd HGGF     UYTT
5 <NA> fFFF     OOOO
```

Applying a loop to find the lines with 'tbd' in the column Col1 of your data frame and build a new one, without 'tbd', by selecting only the lines in Col1 with 'NA'

```
df1 <- c()
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  if(is.na(df$Col1[i])){
    df1 <- rbind(df1,df[i,])
  }
}
```

Resulting in:

```
> df1
  Col1 Name Addreess
1 <NA>  ABC   ddfddf
2 <NA>  XYZ     HJJJ
3 <NA>  KKL     PPOI
5 <NA> fFFF     OOOO
```

**EDIT!**

There's an easier and elegant way to perform this:

```
v <- which(df$Col1 %in% 'tbd')
df <- df[-v,]
```

I hope that helps you.

Regards.

Comment: This worked. I just realized there are some other values too in that column apart from NA, tbd which i don't want to drop. So, I justw ant to exclude tbd... is there a way I can modify that for loop to check tbd in place of is.na function?

Comment: You can use an option to the loop in this case. Apply a command to find the 'tbd' positions: v <- which(df$Col1 %in% 'tbd'), and then make the output without those positions: df[-v,]. It's also a more elegant way to remake my answer.